# Given an undirected graph, is it possible to find a spanning tree of minimum height?

Tags: tree, breadth-first-search, minimum-spanning-tree, graph-traversal, topological-sort

This was a question my professor asked in class and I'm a bit confused.

I was thinking of just traversing the graph to obtain a tree. Then, to determine the minimum height, take each vertex of the tree as the root, and compare heights. This is a brute force method though, and am thinking of a more elegant solution.

I found this website http://buttercola.blogspot.com/2016/01/leetcode-minimum-height-trees.html explaining how they obtained a minimum height tree using something similar to BFS topological sort.

According to the OP, we take two pointers and point them at vertex of degree 1 (leaves), and we have them move at the same speed. When the two meet, we find the root. But this confuses me because how can we ensure that we've picked the correct leaf (what if there's one with a longer path?)

If anyone can help me understand this more, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He didn't stop after 2 two pointers meet. He kept one of them, which now points to an internal node (which *may be* root). Then selects two completely new leaf pointers, but before I proceed any further, you need to understand how that "BFS Topological sort" thing works.

Despite the hard name, it's actually very simple. If our answer tree have height `h`, we find all the leaves and delete them. Which turns every internal node at depth `h-1` into new leaves. We delete them again, which produces new leaves at `h-2` and so on unless we reach height 0, which gives us our root(s).

So when those two pointers met in a node, it's either root, or an internal node that will become leaf in future. In that case, at some point in future, it will partner with another node of same height for above procedure, and lead us to root, or maybe another internal node which then will.......

My advice, forget this two pointers thing entirely. It was done to draw parallel to that "path Graph" example, but which in said tutorial only adds confusion to an otherwise simple concept.

But while thinking about it, I stumbled upon another algorithm which I believe to be even simpler than that "BFS Topological sort" thing (at least implementation-wise). Choose *any* node as root, do a post-order traversal to find all of it's children's heights. Say our root has 3 childs with heights `[2,3,8]`. Think what happens if we transfer "root-ship" to the `8`. All of it's past children has height < 8. And the new one i.e our current root has height 4 (2nd highest = 3,plus one). So, overall height is now 8. (Or lower, we can find that by repeating what we did to our root now for `8`, recursively.)